# How to publish & consume a SOAP web service in an application server container?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I am using bottom to top approach to develop a SOAP web service. I am generating WSDL from `@WebService` SEI java class using Apache cxf maven plugin. I am generating stubs from the WSDL using cxf maven plugin.

After getting done with this, now I need to know how to publish the webservice endpoint which is mentioned as `'<soap:address location..'` in my WSDL. In my case while using JBoss, I see `http://localhost:9090/SEINamePort` as endpoint address in WSDL. Looks like I need to publish this.

Please guide me what are the best ways to publish & consume this endpoint in an application deployed in an EE application server container.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the things as simple as possible, if you're using JBoss you could create an EJB and add the WebService annotation, say:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class MyClass{

   public int multiply(int a, int b){
      return a * b;
   }
}
```

And the Webservice will be published automatically. If you want to create the web service client, you just need to use the wsimport tool from the jdk of this way:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://ip:port/yourwebservice/ws?wsdl
```

-keep to save the generated classes
-verbose to print in the console the output (optional)

Here is a useful link for you:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/